# How to create such layout in CSS?

Tags: css

Here's what I tried: http://jsfiddle.net/tJxCD/6/

I want to create a layout like this:
[image]

But I don't know how to make the third rectangle on bottom of the second.

Comment: If you look at the jsfiddle it is quite clear as there are only three divs.

Comment: The one on right/bottom on the picture.

Comment: @blez could you please fill rectangles with different colors? And then tell to us the color of rectangle you want to "fix"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

http://jsfiddle.net/kHT8z/1/

```
.wrapper {
    overflow: hidden;
    width: 500px
}

.top {
    border: 3px solid #000;
    width: 300px;
    height: 170px;
    margin: 5px;
    float: left;
 }

.right {
    border: 3px solid #000;
    width: 150px;
    height: 75px;
    margin: 5px;
    float: left;
 }

.bottom_small {
    border: 3px solid #000;
    float: left;
    margin: 5px;
    height: 50px;
    width: 90px;
}

.bottom_big {
    border: 3px solid #000;
    float: left;
    margin: 5px;
    height: 75px;
    width: 150px;
}


<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="top"></div>
    <div class="right"></div>
    <div class="right"></div>
</div>

<div class="bottom_big"></div>
<div class="bottom_small"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Hard to tell exactly what your after but your divs can share several css properties and you can use classes to specify size only. This [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/tJxCD/8/) represents your diagram.
Of course this layout is dependent on the width of the containing element, in this case the body, so you need to be aware of that.

HTML layout:

```
<html><body>
<div class="large"></div>
<div class="medium"></div>
<div class="medium"></div>
<div class="medium"></div>
<div class="small"></div>
</body></html>
```

CSS:

```
div {
  border: 1px solid gray;
  margin: 5px 5px 0 0;
  float: left;
}

div.large{
  width: 300px;
  height: 175px;
 }

 div.medium {
  width: 150px;
  height: 84px;
 }
 div.small{
  width: 100px;
  height: 44px;
}
```